# Increment excel rows from a specific row and store the data into list using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have 4 columns in my excel sheet. i need to read all the rows of 4 columns and store the data into the lists using c#. For this, i am trying to increment the rows and storing the data into  4 lists.
Can anybody tell me how can do this?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I have not written the code...i am not able to write it ..need some help in that

Comment: give more details of the problem... code and expected result

Comment: @ayushidixit please search sample code on internet for that

Comment: Excel contains four columns and every column is having data in it. i need to store all the rows of the excel sheet into lists which i have declared publicly. So that i can access those list.As i am loading the data from excel sheet to windows form. the single cell data in coming by giving the specific cell number. But for the columns which are containing multiple data, how can i extract all the data from that column. So i was trying to use list.

Comment: I am not getting any sample code.. @ Raghavendra